# PhpMyAdmin is asking to connect to a remote server

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have installed XAMPP Server on my machine, as soon as I load localhost/phpmyadmin/ I get a pop up from ESET Smart Security asking about an authorization of an outbound connection. I am surprised as this is supposed to be a local server.
I tried many times and I was getting the same pop up, please see the screenshots :

http://postimg.org/image/90aysaq9f/

http://postimg.org/image/oyg6tswod/

As u can see one it is trying to connect to cdn77.com, the other one is trying to connect to Turkey Datacenter

PS : the same happens whne I installed WAMP Server

How this can happen ? and how safe is it to allow connection to this remote servers ?

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin checks for updates when launched. CDN77 is the CDN network that distributes the phpMyAdmin downloads, although I'm not as confident about the other screenshot you've posted. Looking at the host for phpmyadmin.net it's a different IP address, although it's likely that's what it is I can't confirm that at the moment.

You can disable this version check by entering `$cfg['VersionCheck'] = false;` in your `config.inc.php`. See http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_VersionCheck for details.